# How to call stored procedure within function by output value, then get and return this value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have a sp "spGetNewNumber" that return a value as new number as below:

```
USE [MyPhoneDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spsRouteRules_getNewNumber]
          @oldNumber NVARCHAR(15),
          @newNumber NVARCHAR(15) = '0' OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT newTellNo as newNumber FROM changedPhones WHERE oldTelNo = @oldNumber;
END
```

Now I need a Function can call this stored procedure and return value from sp.

I try to use this code from stackoverflow such as below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION fnGetNewNumber 
(
    @oldNumber bigint
)
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
        -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @returnValue bigint
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(500)

    SELECT @SQL = 'osql -S' +@@servername +' -E -q "exec spsRouteRules_getNewNumber ' + CONVERT(nchar, @oldNumber)
    -- SELECT @SQL
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQL,'@returnValue bigint output', @returnValue output

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @returnValue;

END
GO
```

but not answered this function and method.

Comment: Simple Answer, You cannot call a procedure inside a function. But you can call this stored procedure from another stored procedure.

Comment: @M.Ali . . . You *can* call an extended stored procedure in a function, and `xp_cmdshell` is an extended stored procedure.

Comment: This whole question seems ridiculous.  If this is the real problem, why not just make the first stored procedure a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use function instead of stored procedure in order to get new value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[spsRouteRules_getNewNumber](@oldNumber NVARCHAR(15))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(15)
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    RETURN ISNULL(SELECT TOP 1 newTellNo FROM changedPhones WHERE oldTelNo = @oldNumber),0);
END
```

You can't call user definition stored procedure inside a function. you can only call your stored procedure inside of another stored procedure.